# How do I use italicized capital Greek letters in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, drawing

1. `$\it{\Delta}$` is useless as it will print Δ and not *Δ*
2. We can use `\varDelta` in LaTex to get the *Δ*, but it is useless in Matplotlib
3. It is inappropriate to use slanted text，because I want to print something like "*Δ*/mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the Latex package `amsmath` and then use `$\mathit{\Delta}$` in the label.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib import rcParams

matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
params = {'text.latex.preamble': [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']}   
plt.rcParams.update(params)       

fig, ax = plt.subplots()  

ax.plot([1],[1], 'bo')
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\mathit{\Delta}$/mm')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\Delta$/mm')

plt.show()
```

which produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
It's a little hard for me to use LaTex.And I have found a more simple method：we can use local fontfamilyand fontstyle to avoid operating in LaTex，like `plt.title(r"Δ$\rm{/mm}$", family=['Times New Roman'], style='italic')`

Comment: @TianBian Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer so that it does not show up in the unanswered queue.